# how to make a complicated query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have store table, product table and a store-product table showing their relationship.

```
*store table*
store_id  name ...
1         store1
2         store2
3         store3

*product table*
product_id name ...
1          product1
2          product2
3          product3

*store-product table*
id    store_id product_id
1     1        1
2     1        2
3     2        3
4     3        1
5     3        2
6     3        3
```

Once products are given, I want to get stores that are selling those products.

i.e: If the given product is `1`, then stores `1, 3` should be fetched.

If the given products are `1, 2, 3`, then only store `3` should be fetched.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: *"If the given product is 1, then stores 1, 3 should be fetched.

If the given products are 1, 2, 3, then only store 3 should be fetched."* what if a product is only  2, 3 or 4 or 10000000 for that matter..

Comment: If only one product is given, then all stores selling the product should be fetched.

Comment: See mine first comment and make some better explainment and cases for this question as outputs per case tells more then1000 words.. Also it is still not clear how you output should look like..

Comment: I've prepared a sqlfiddle for you. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf2415 just a sec.

Comment: *"If the given products are 1, 2, 3, then only store 3 should be fetched."* Also i assume this is not orded related?  if the order is `1, 3, 2` for example you don't expect only store `2` to be fetched right as `2` is last in that order? .. Just checking..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select sp.store_id
from store_product sp
where sp.product_id in (1, 2, 3)  -- list of products
group by sp.store_id
having count(*) = 3;              -- number of elements in list
```

Comment: *"We have so many products and i think it won't work."* @tomcarrier MySQL can handle billions off records when indexes, tables and queries are designed correctly  ...

Comment: in this case @tomcarrier you want the index to be atleast `store_product(product_id, store_id)`  for this index you also might want to change `having count(*) = 3; ` in `having count(sp.product_id) = 3;` instead to make sure that the MySQL optimizer is not possibly get a wierd idea from side stepping from using that covering index..

Comment: Sorry, but I think you misunderstood my question. The question is, "Once the product list (1, 2) is given, stores 1 and 3 should be fetched". Please take a careful look at store-product table.

Comment: I checked it again, works quite well, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Shortened table names, but something like this?

```
select store.name from pt
    join spt on spt.product_id = pt.id
    join st on spt.store_id = st.id
where st.product_id = 1
```

Comment: Well, that is the easy case, what about `1,2,3` as list of products?

Comment: `where st.product_id = 1 or st.product_id = 2` or `where st.product_id IN (1,2,3)`

Comment: No. `3` is supposed to be the resulting store id. So you need to do something like `having count(*) = 3`

Comment: Do you want the store that has all three products? I don't understand your last example, because that should not return store 1 in that case...

Comment: No, I want the stores that contain all the given products.